# Can I use Visual C# 2010 express to create a MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm coming from java so this is entirely new to me. I have Visual C# 2010 Express installed and I'd like to create a ASP.NET MVC 3.0 (which I downloaded and installed) application. Is that possible? Should I install Visual Web Developer instead?

Comment: I was hoping in some kind of "plug-in" architecture. I guess Visual C# and Web Developer share a lot of code, so it should be simple to just add pieces. Oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. To create Web Apps, you need  Visual Web Developer Express. Visual C# 2010 Express if for console applications and windows forms application.

You can install Visual Studio 2012 Express edition which includes ASP.NET MVC 4 from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to install [Visual Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express), yes. Basically Visual C# Express is for non-web apps, IIRC.

Note that if you're going to install a new version anyway, you might as well upgrade to VS 2012 which is now available (including in Express editions).

Answer (score 0):

Please , visit http://www.asp.net/mvc and follow steps in Overview